# Why is understanding this recursion example so difficult to put into intuition?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have difficulties to understand this code. I can fully understand why foo() is printing that values but I just can't get my head around why bar() is printing those in reverse. Can anyone please anyhow explain this so that I can feel it intuitively or at least give me a direction where to go for to reach the absolution.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void bar(int a){
    cout<<"bar: "<<a<<endl;
}

void foo(int a){
    if(a>0){
        a -=1;
        cout<<"foo: "<<a<<endl;
        foo(a);
        bar(a);
    }else{
        cout<<"Foo exited"<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    foo(10);
}

[Output]:
foo: 9
foo: 8
foo: 7
foo: 6
foo: 5
foo: 4
foo: 3
foo: 2
foo: 1
foo: 0
Foo exited
bar: 0
bar: 1
bar: 2
bar: 3
bar: 4
bar: 5
bar: 6
bar: 7
bar: 8
bar: 9
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript?

Comment: No sir, it isn't, it's in C++ but the JavaScript one doesn't look like very different. They are kind of same paradigm as far as it is about this piece of code at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the program in a debugger?  It would show the flow never reaches the bar function until the foo function has been called recursively 11 times.  The "stack" at that point contains 10 instances of an instruction pointer pointing to the bar function along with the local values of a.  The stack is unwound from the bottom up (stack = LIFO last in first out).  Does that make sense?

If it doesn't, then by all means run it in a debugger, while watching the stack values (instruction pointer and local variables).

Answer (score 5):

Recursion is best understood if you don’t try to „run the whole callstack in your head“. Think in abstractions:

1. You print n
2. You go one level down
3. After you return you print n again

As such the output of a "single level" would be (e.g for `foo(10)`):

```
Foo 9
output of foo(9)
Bar 9
```

Resolving one more level by filling in the partial output of foo(9)

```
Foo 9
Foo 8
output of foo(8)
Bar 8
Bar 9
```

This pattern continues until we reach the end of recursion.

The code might look like it is sequential `foo();bar();` (which it is) but `foo()` first descents which leads to `bar()` being called just before ascending the callstack.

Answer (score 4):

The calls are as follows (limited to 5 levels):

```
foo(5)
    foo(4)
        foo(3)
            foo(2)
                foo(1)
                    foo(0)
                    bar(0)
                bar(1)
            bar(2)
         bar(3)
     bar(4)
bar(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the calls are to different functions then which function hits the line `cout<<"foo: "<<a<<endl;` first? And which of those imaginary functions calls `bar()` first?

The first call only calls `bar()` after all the other calls already returned!

Instead of thinking of different functions you can manually inline the calls to easier follow what happens:

```
void foo(int a){
    if(a>0){
        a -=1;
        cout<<"foo: "<<a<<endl;
        // foo(a); // inline this...
        if(a>0){
            a -=1;
            cout<<"foo: "<<a<<endl;
            // foo(a); // inline this again
            if(a>0){
                a -=1;
                cout<<"foo: "<<a<<endl;
                foo(a); // and turtles all the way down...
                bar(a);
            }else{
                cout<<"Foo exited"<<endl;
            }
            bar(a);
        }else{
            cout<<"Foo exited"<<endl;
        }
        bar(a);
    }else{
        cout<<"Foo exited"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all due to the stack (which is the namesake of this site, BTW). The stack is how a programming language knows how to get back to where it's been after a function (or method or subroutine, etc...) is exited. Every function call is added (pushed onto) to the stack (along with the parameters passed to the function...this is not important here). A stack is two things here, it is both the name of the object holding the data and the name of the class which defines it (which will be important to know later). The value added to the stack is a pointer to where the call was made from; just to be clear, it isn't pointing to the function definition but to the line that called the function. As the program returns from these functions (because you used return or an implied return right before the curly brackets) it pops the stack so that it knows where to move the instruction pointer to next.

In your example, foo() is pushed onto the stack 11 times (the last time it just prints the exit line) before bar() is pushed at all because bar() comes after foo() and foo() is called the second time (and a third call, fourth call, and so on) before the first bar() is called. Each of these calls will increment and print the value and then push another foo() on the stack. Once the foo()s have all been called but before any of them have been removed from the stack, the foo() functions each push bar() onto the stack (it's the next line after the recursive line), wait for bar(n) to finish and then they exit which drops us down to the previous recursion. Because these foo() functions were placed onto the stack in forward order and it recurses *before* calling bar(), they pop bar()s from the stack in reverse order (remember, a stack is a FILO data structure). This is why it appears to count down; even though it is actually just showing the count up results in reverse order. By the way, bar() doesn't need to exist for this to work like this, you could've just added the cout directly after the recursive foo() call and it would've worked the same.

Anytime you are doing recursion you must think about the stack because it fills up quickly and when it does your program will crash. This crash is actually a good thing because, otherwise, the entire application would just hang. That doesn't sound much better but it lets you get on with your life sooner so it is great. Also, you're probably going to find that avoiding what is happening here is usually a good thing unless you specifically want bar() to be called in reverse order of foo(). In general, it is far easier to follow recursion if the recursion is at the end of the recursive function whenever possible.